# 'Duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed' when using struct2geno in LEA

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a structure file of SNP data to a geno file using `struct2geno` in LEA

```
struct2geno ("gl.str", ploidy = 2, FORMAT = 2, extra.row = 1, extra.column = 0)
```

My data is diploid, hence `ploidy = 2`.
I have 2 rows of data per individual, hence `FORMAT = 2`
I have one row of header, hence `extra.row = 1`
The missing data is coded as -9.
The first column is the id, so `extra.column = 0` as  I don’t consider that to be an extra column. Maybe it is?

[Image of part of the structure file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuZUM.jpg)

The following error message is returned:

```
Error in read.table(input.file) : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

I have read countless questions with `duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`, but none are my problem.
Has anyone any idea what I have done wrong please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this myself by using a differnt route:

I had a genlight file.

I converted the genlight to a genind using `gl2gi`

Then genind to structure`genind2structure`

And finally, structure to geno using `struct2geno`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for putting up your answer. A couple of years on from your post, I did something similar, and thought I would post it in case it was helpful.

```
#Step 1. Convert genlight object 'gl' to a structure file using package dartR.
gl2structure(gl, indNames = NULL, addcolumns = gl@pop, ploidy = 2, 
exportMarkerNames = TRUE, outfile = "gl.str", outpath = getwd(), verbose = 5)

#Step 2. In Notepad++ first add two new columns names 'ind' and 'pop', 
# separated by tabs to push the locus names by two columns.

#Step 3. Convert structure file to geno object using package LEA.
geno <-struct2geno("D:/add.path.here/LEA_analyses/gl.str", ploidy = 2, FORMAT=2,
extra.row=1, extra.column=2)
```

It is a great idea to make sure you are always aware of the order of your samples when you go to label them later with population information.